# How to store the arguments for a large amount of objects?

Tags: java, database, object, oop

What I plan to do is create a large set of objects (~500). Currently I have a large Java file in which I create all objects in the following form:

```
MyCollection.add(String name, int strength, int size, int price);
```

But with this it takes a lot of space and I don't think it is the best way.
I don't really know my way around in this area. How is such a problem normally handled? Would it make sense to create a CSV file or another database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where this data comes from. Do you generate it on runtime? If so - consider **abstraction**, so that you define a proper structure of objects and encapsulate this data and the process of creating it properly. If the data is static then yes, a database of any sort makes more sense. Specifically this means making your data persistent and simplifying the process of reading it as much as possible, *e.g.* reading the data via loop, encapsulating it in an objcect `MyFancyEntry`, then adding it to your collection.

You are in my opinion also right about 500 manual `add` calls on a `Collection` being bad design. The reason is simple - maintainability.

1. It is hard to change the structure quickly, if upon a structural change you suddenly need to edit 500 lines by hand.
2. There is also more room for mistakes, when you have so many identical repeating lines.

Comment: Configuring a database for just 500 static entries is a bit overkill. A plain & simple `.txt` file (or any other format) would be enough.

Comment: That's true. I suppose my focus is on the persistence of static data, while a database also introduces organizational structures that are not required at this size.